# Adding random 'interesting people' to user events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

so I've created a web app that has user profiles, where users can search for fellow users based on interests, and create events etc.. How might I add a feature on the events page that says 'interesting people' and randomly shows the profile_image of 5 users, and changes on every refresh.

_event.html.erb

```
div id="event_<%= event.id %>">                                                                                                                              
  <div class="span2">                                                                                                                                         
  <% if event.user.profile_image.present? %>                                                                                                                  
    <%= image_tag event.user.profile_image_url(:thumb), class: 'img-polaroid' %>                                                                              
  <% else %>                                                                                                                                                  
    <%= image_tag "profile-placeholder1.png" %>                                                                                                               
  <% end %>                                                                                                                                                   
  </div>                                                                                                                                                      
  <div class="span3">                                                                                                                                         
    <div class="line2">                                                                                                                                       
    <h5><%= link_to_event_owner(event.user) %> Created an Event</h5>                                                                                          
    <h4><%= link_to event.title, event %></h4>                                                                                                                
    <h5><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <%= event.location %></h5>                                                                                           
    <h5><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> <%= event.date.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y") %></h5>                                                                     
    <h5><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <%= event.time %></h5>                                                                                                  
    <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> <medium><strong align-"center"><%= pluralize(event.participants.size.to_s, 'person') %></strong></medium> <br /><br />
        <% event.participants.each do |p| %>                                                                                                                  
            <%= simple_user_avatar(p) %>                                                                                                                      
            <%= p.short_name %> is attending.                                                                                                                 
        <% end %>                                                                                                                                             
    </div>                                                                                                                                                    
  </div>                                                                                                                                                      
</div>                                                                                                                                                        
<div class="clearfix"></div>                                                                                                                                  
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by doing the following:

In the controller event that renders _event.html.erb (e.g, show) do something like this

```
def show
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  # get 5 random attendees. I don't know about your model so this is just an example.
  #You could very well search other model. For example, People.order("RAND()").first(5)..
  @intersting_people = @event.attendees.order("RAND()").first(5)
end
```

Then in your view loop through @intersting_people and display

```
<% @interesting_people.each do |person| %>
  <%= person.first_name %>
<% end %>
```

That's just an example of what you could do. Good luck!